# Hudson fails Maven2 build sporadically - missing webdav

Tags: java, maven-2, hudson

Every few weeks my Hudson build fails and I get this error output.  When I delete my entire .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-webdav directory and kick off another build without that dependency in the repo, it resolves the problem for a few weeks.

I never see this error outside of Hudson.  I'm on Maven 2.2.1 and Hudson 1.378.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav: checking for updates from relrepo
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav: checking for updates from central
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:jar:RELEASE

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.wagon -DartifactId=wagon-webdav -Dversion=RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.wagon -DartifactId=wagon-webdav -Dversion=RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.my-company-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:jar:RELEASE
```

Comment: Is hudson running on a 64 bit machine with 64 bit jvm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you depending on an artifact version of `RELEASE`? I don't think this is recommended any more and it is one of the few features that is actually [not supported in maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution). Can you try depending on a specific version number? That would also make your build more easily reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to maven3 and make sure all your plugins are latest versions. There are lots of intermittent/transient issues that have been fixed in both plugins and maven3. The hudson<->m3 issue might not be fixed yet, so you might have to start with the plugins.

Comment: Um, he's using Maven 2.2.1.  Why should he migrate to Maven 3 if there are still plugin issues between Hudson and Maven?

Comment: They seem to have been solved during xmas ;) Don't know if his Hudson is fresh enough though...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to execute mvn install -U. However i'm not completly sure if this only affects SNAPSHOT versions.